# JMeter generating same random number for each iteration

Tags: jmeter

I've got some user defined variables to which I allocate a random number using:

```
${__Random(1,100)}
```

I then run my test using 1 thread for 5 iterations. JMeter generates the same random number for each iteration.

How do I generate a new random number for each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add as first  step of Thread Group a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)

Put inside it a pre processor called [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) and click Add Variable

And put in it what you currently have in User Defined Variable

[image: User Defined Variable]

Answer (score 3):

[User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) is a [configuration element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) which means that:

1. It is processed **before** any other elements
2. It is processed **once**

So just use this __Random() function directly where required.

[image]

If you need to re-use the value in more than one place - amend your function call like:

```
${__Random(1,100,myValue)}
```

and after that declaration you will be able to refer random generated value as `${myValue}`

[image]